# Is there a website that will create a help file?

Tags: webapp-rec

I want to generate a help file or a help website similar to .chm files or MSDN. I have lots of Word documents which need to be converted to either of the above mentioned formats.

I do not want to create .chm or help website using offline tools like HTML help workshop.

Please post your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

We've used [Google Sites](http://sites.google.com/) to host our 'help' section and it works great. Google Sites has some Wiki based templates that you can start with. These can be styled to suit your requirements using either a WYSIWYG editor or by editing the HTML.
 Google Sites also allows you to collaborate and view old changes. Its dead easy to get started and I would definitely encourage you to give it a shot.

Comment: and the part where the existing word documents are converted into a google-site comes ... when?

Comment: I tried, but it is not what I'm looking for... 
I need to upload word documents, google site doesn't have the feature to do that; and you have to manually create each page :(

Comment: Hi guys, sorry about that.I missed the 'upload docs' part.

Comment: You can upload to Google Docs... but you're not going to be able to convert them to .chm...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should take a step back and think about why you're using word documents as the basis of your help section.  It seems a bit backwards to me.

Just move it all once into something online and leave it there and updated it there, why does it need to be live it's life as a Word document?

You say you don't want .chm files in your post, so I'm guessing what you're chasing is something more like the MSDN style of presentation.  This is a pretty common style of presentation for API docs generated with JavaDOC/PHPDOC/nDoc and many other generators, but you're still not going to be able to use word documents.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Offisync](http://www.offisync.com/) you can upload your Word files directly to [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com) and [Google Sites](http://sites.google.com) and work on them directly from Microsoft Word.

Once they are uploaded you can use the Google web app sites instead of Word itself.

As for CHM files - you can use [Offline CHM](http://www.freedownloadscenter.com/Web_Authoring/Automated_Web_Publishing_Tools/Offline_CHM.html) to convert the Google Site into a CHM file.

This should help your workflow: use Word, have a website, ability for occasionally run off CHM files and use web apps as well.

Total cost is $30.00 (for Offline CHM) and a $50.00 (per user) subscription to [Google Premier](http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/index.html) if you feel the need for it.